# Can I plot a beta distributed model with percentage rather than proportion?

Tags: beta-distribution, ggplot2, beta-regression

I am analyzing a response variable (herbivory) which is a proportion, so I am using betareg function from the betareg package. The structure is similar to the GasolineYield dataset, so using it as example:

```
data("GasolineYield", package = "betareg")

GasolineYield.subset <- GasolineYield[GasolineYield$batch == "4" | GasolineYield$batch == "5" | GasolineYield$batch== "6", ]#subsetting 3 levels to make it simpler

gy_logit <- betareg(yield ~ temp+batch, data = GasolineYield.subset)

summary(gy_logit)

Call:
betareg(formula = yield ~ temp + batch, data = GasolineYield.subset)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.9386 -1.2146 -0.0026  1.1988  1.6652 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -5.1064266  0.1626427 -31.397   <2e-16 ***
temp         0.0109771  0.0004478  24.514   <2e-16 ***
batch5       0.0749215  0.0520939   1.438     0.15    
batch6      -0.0192368  0.0536873  -0.358     0.72    

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(phi)   1282.6      573.5   2.237   0.0253 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 30.99 on 5 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.9883
Number of iterations: 859 (BFGS) + 5 (Fisher scoring)
```

However, the literature in the field suggests to plot this variable as a percentage rather than as a proportion.

My questions are:

1-Can I just adjust a betareg model with proportional data but plot it as a percentage? Maybe, by multiplying the proportion column by 100, and using it in Y axis? e.g: GasolineYield.subset'$'yield*100

2- If so, how do I obtain the predicted lines? I ask because I can't adjust another betareg model using the percentage data, as all observations must be in (0, 1). To make it clearer, I am plotting the betareg model in ggplot2 as follows. How would I do if I use a percentage data?

Thank you very much.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(GasolineYield.subset, (aes(x=temp, y=yield, color=batch, shape=batch))) +  geom_point() + 
geom_line(aes(y=predict(gy_logit, GasolineYield.subset),linetype = batch))+
  theme(panel.background=element_blank(),
        legend.position="right",
        text = element_text(size=16),axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"), axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black"), axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size=.8, lineend="round"), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size=.8, lineend="round"))+
  scale_x_continuous("Temperature", breaks=seq(200,450, 50))
```

[image]

Comment: This is probably better suited for StackOverflow. But can this be solved simply by adding `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(.1, .2, .3), labels = c("10", "20", "30"))` ?

Comment: Thanks @klumbard. Yes, this should work. But the main issue is not about the plot, as in this case I would just change the labels, but still plotting a model as a percentage that 'originally' was a proportion. What about the first question – is it statistically correct to do that?

Comment: I cannot see the problem here. Percentages are just proportions surely? Why not do everything on the scale of proportions and then just re-label everything at the last minute?

Comment: @mdewey yes, that's my intention. I was just wondering if there was any statistical problem with this approach. In the end, betareg does not run with Y values larger than 1, and I was insecure to report a plot with % and describing it as a model from betareg() function. But it seems it's ok, right?. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *mean model* portion of the beta regression model you fitted to your data has the following form:

$\log(\mu/(1-\mu)) = \beta_0 + \beta_1*temp + \beta_2*batch5 + \beta_3*batch6$

where $\mu$ represents the expected (or mean) yield, with yield being expressed as a proportion.

For plotting purposes, it is easier if you re-express the above equation as:

$\mu = \exp(lp)/(1 + \exp(lp))$

where $lp$ (linear predictor) stands for $\beta_0 + \beta_1*temp + \beta_2*batch5 + \beta_3*batch6$.

In this last equation, $\mu$ is the expected yield expressed as a proportion, so multiplying both sides of the equation by 100% would give:

$\mu * 100\% = \exp(lp)/(1 + \exp(lp)) * 100\%$.

Now, $\mu * 100\%$ represents the expected yield expressed as a percentage.

Of course, in practice, you have to replace the $\beta$ coefficients by their estimated values reported by R, and multiply by $100$ instead of $100\%$ to do your plotting (since the $\%$ symbol can be manually added to the ticks located on the vertical axis of your plot).

For example, you would plot:

$\exp(b_0 + b_1*temp)/(1 + \exp(b_0 + b_1*temp)) * 100$ versus $temp$ to display the effect of $temp$ on expected yield (expressed as a percentage) for batch 4;

$\exp(b_0 + b_2 + b_1*temp)/(1 + \exp(b_0 + b_2 + b_1*temp)) * 100$ versus $temp$ to display the effect of $temp$ on expected yield (expressed as a percentage) for batch 5;

$\exp(b_0 + b3 + b_1*temp)/(1 + \exp(b_0 + b_3 + b_1*temp)) * 100$ versus $temp$ to display the effect of $temp$ on expected yield (expressed as a percentage) for batch 6.

Here, the $b$s denote the estimated values of the $\beta$s which are reported in R's output:

```
> summary(gy_logit)

Call:
betareg(formula = yield ~ temp + batch, data = GasolineYield.subset)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.9386 -1.2146 -0.0026  1.1988  1.6652 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) b0 = -5.1064266  0.1626427 -31.397   <2e-16 ***
temp        b1 =  0.0109771  0.0004478  24.514   <2e-16 ***
batch5      b2 =  0.0749215  0.0520939   1.438     0.15    
batch6      b3 = -0.0192368  0.0536873  -0.358     0.72    

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(phi)   1282.6      573.5   2.237   0.0253 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 30.99 on 5 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.9883
Number of iterations: 859 (BFGS) + 5 (Fisher scoring)
```

Thus, you are right that you can switch your plotting scale for the y-axis from proportion to percentage using the strategy explained above.

If your variable was expressed as a proportion and analyzed as a proportion via beta regression, then you can clearly state that in your write-up.  Then you can add that the results of the beta regression modelling were visualized on the percentage (rather than proportion) scale on the vertical axis of the plot for ease of interpretation.

The *effects* package in R comes in handy for these types of visualizations - I recently wrote something about this, which you can find here: http://www.ghement.ca/EffectPlotsBetaRegression.docx.

Comment: Excellent – thank you for your response and for the link! Very useful.

Comment: @Lucnp: You're welcome! I edited my answer to make it clear who the b coefficients are in relation to the R output.